# Filter Quicksight dataset by multiple values from other dataset

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I'm very very new to QuickSight.
I want to create some sort of "preset" filters on my table analysis which will filter the dataset by multiple values. It is hard to explain by word so let me just show an example:

I have the following "item_orders" dataset:

```
| id | category     | name            | sold |
|----|--------------|-----------------|------|
| 1  | game_console | PS4             |  2   |
| 2  | tv           | Sony LED TV     |  3   |
| 3  | cell_phone   | Apple iPhone    |  1   |
| 4  | tablet       | Apple iPad      |  2   |
```

And I have "category_group" dataset:

```
| group_name         | category      |
|------------------------------------|
| home_electronics   | game_console  |
| home_electronics   | tv            |
| mobile_electronics | cell_phone    |
| mobile_electronics | tablet        |
| electronics        | game_console  |
| electronics        | tv            |
| electronics        | cell_phone    |
| electronics        | tablet        |
```

Now, what I want to do is I want to be able to filter the "item_orders" dataset using the "category group" dataset's "group_name" field.

For example, if I filter by "home_electronics", then it should return "PS4" and "Sony LED TV"
If I filter by "mobile_electronics" then it should return "Apple iPhone" and "Apple iPad"
and If I filter by "electronics" then it should return "PS4", "Sony LED TV", "Apple iPhone" and "Apple iPad"

I have managed to create the control and populate the value with "category_group.group_name" values, however, I'm struggling to filter "item_orders" based on the selected group_name.

I'd appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*******Did this answer help you resolve your problem?

1. Click on the visual that contains your data set items_orders
2. Click on the filter button at the left side of the screen

[image]

3. Click on the + Sign to select the fields you can filter by. Select category.
   [image]
4. In the menu the opens, click "use parameter"

[image]

4a. You will receive a popup box asking if you want to filter all visuals with the control. Click yes or no.

5. Select the parameter which applies to the control you made for the category field.
6. Click Apply and Close the filter window
7. Voila